# How can I server Craft transform assets statically (not through Craft/PHP)

Tags: server, performance, image-transforms

I’m using Craft as a backend for an iOS app and theres thousands of asset requests.

Having to go through php instead of straight through Apache is causing too much of a bottleneck.

I want to use Craft's transforms, but I want the resulting URL to be statically accessible (directly through apache), and not have to go through Craft at all.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

This happens automatically if you use `asset.getUrl(transform)`...